# tf.map_fn and Defun clash

Tags: tensorflow

I'am trying to define my own operation in tensorflow using the @function.Defun decorator, because i need to equip it with a custom gradient. However, in my code i also needs to call the tf.map_fn function, to apply a specific function to a batch of data. For simplicity i am trying to do something like:

```
def add_func(x):
    return x+1

@function.Defun(tf.float32)
def test(a):
    return tf.map_fn(add, a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.ones(shape=(6,1))
    res = sess.run(test(a))
```

This code runs fine without the @function.Defun decorator, but using the decorator I get the the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 25 nodes in a cycle
     [[Node: test_8028ca0d_2 = test_8028ca0d[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ones_4)]]

Caused by op 'test_8028ca0d_2', defined at:
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 219, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-c5e48d04d428>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Nicki/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nicki/.spyder-py3')
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Nicki/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 156, in <module>
    res = sess.run(test(a))
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\function.py", line 618, in __call__
    return _call(self._definition.signature, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\function.py", line 271, in _call
    compute_shapes=False)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Nicki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): 25 nodes in a cycle
     [[Node: test_8028ca0d_2 = test_8028ca0d[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ones_4)]]
```

Comment: It sounds like you've found a bug in the `Defun` implementation. I've posted this as a GitHub issue and we'll follow up there: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8332

Comment: Thanks :) I know that the Defun implementation is still experimental, but as I understand it is the only way to equip self defined operations with gradients and still run on the gpu.

Comment: This is definitely something we should support (or provide a better error for)!  My colleague needs a little more information to fix the issue—would you be able to ping the GitHub issue to close the loop here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this question, the [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8332) revealed that the problem exists in an older version of TensorFlow (0.12 or earlier). Upgrading to TensorFlow 1.0 fixes the problem.